# Получение спектра звука аудио файла в android

Tags: android, аудио

Подскажите, как получить и отобразить **спектр** звука аудио-файла?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно преобразование Фурье. То есть исходный аудио сигнал надо засунуть в преобразователь Фурье - он его разложит на гармоники - что и является спектром звукового сигнала.

Обычно принято использовать алгоритм [FFT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) (Fast Fourier Transformation), библиотек для расчета FFT полно - берите и занимайтесь.

Удачи.

**Update**

Если вы захотите сами реализовать - то это довольно сложная задача. Примерная траектория будет такая:

1. Перевести исходный аудио-файл (в какой бы он там сжатом формате не был) в сырой (raw) поток данных, в т.н. [импульсно-модулированную (PCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) форму - то есть в том виде в котором он подается на динамики. То есть когда у вас есть набор сигналов которые записаны некой частотой дискретизации (в стандарте 44.1 кГц), далее кодируется амплитуда сигнала (в идеале 16 бит), звук бывает моно или стерео или того хуже многоканальный.
2. На втором этапе, после того как вы научились получать импульсно-модулированную форму, нужно озаботиться дискретизацией для Фурье преобразования (*stationary interval*) - ну то есть вы не можете единичный raw сигнал превратить в Фурье (конечно можете но получите фигню). Надо брать что-то типа ~10 ms - зависит от много чего в том числе и от вашей вычислительно мощности - успеете ли за 10 ms провести Фурье преобразование?
3. Собственно само Фурье преобразование сигнала накопленного за *stationary interval*
4. Ну потом видимо надо будет отобразить? Отдельная непростая задача...

В общем погуглите, ключевые слова на 1-м этапе: *MP3 raw data java*, дальше *Fast Fourier Transformation java*

Comment: аудио сигнал разве не храниться в спектре в конкретный момент времени?

Comment: Сигнал это функция амплитуда от времени. Спектр это функция амплитуды от частоты. Временная развертка достигается за счет дискретизации входного сигнала на кусочки, скажем копим сигнал за 1 миллисекунду и строим из этого кусочка спектр

Comment: Если у вас есть возможность,посоветуйте где найти норм инфу по извлечению данных для обработки,с mp3 или другого аудио файла.Если нет то и на том спасиба,направили на правильний путь:)

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна спектрограмма аудио для просмотра воспроизводимых частот -- можете сделать это в аудиоредакторе  Audacity. Наберите в гугл Audacity спектр для информации

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ,но мне нужно ети данные потом использовать.